# Pattern Printing in C

Tags: c

Hey I am stuck to find a logic to print this pattern. I tried a lot but can't find any way.

My Problem is:

I have an array which contains some random integers and based on that I have to print stars(*) in vertically format.

For example:

```
array = [2,3,5,2,6];
```

Then the pattern will be:

```
    *
  * *    
  * *
 ** *
*****   
*****
```

Comment: You're missing jQuery as tag

Comment: I can't see any relation between the array and the pattern, can you explain? And please either pick a signle language or none at all, and [tag:design-patterns] has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @iharob: Vertical bars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do this in Java, without temporary arrays ([Java Fiddle here](http://goo.gl/0PBZwk)):

```
 public static void main(String []args){
   final int[] array = new int[]{2,3,5,2,6};

   int max = -1; // Maximum of all integers
   for (int num : array) {
       max = Math.max(max, num);
   }

   for (int vert = 0; vert < max; ++vert) {
       for (int horz = 0; horz < array.length; ++horz) {
           System.out.print(array[horz] >= max-vert ? '*' : ' ');
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Output:

```
    *
  * *
  * *
 ** *
*****
*****
```

Comment: @Tunaki, thanks for the notice; changed that to `println()`. 
Writing to System.out is not good anyway, a much cleaner way would be to return a string. I just wanted to demonstrate the algorithm here, not to build a clean Java method... 
But again, thanks for pointing out the `print('\n')` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i suggest you do.

Initialize a 2D-array. 
With rows equal to the Highest Number in Array. and Columns equal to Number of Integers in Array..

Then you can fill the array with corresponding number of stars, for specific index in array. hope that will at least make you understand One-of-Many logics.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
// insert code here...
int arr[4] = {2,1,4,3};
int max=4;
int count=0;

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    while(count<4)
    {
       if(arr[count]>=max)
       {
           printf("*");
       }
        else
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        count++;
    }
    count=0;
    max--;
    printf("\n");


}

return 0;
}
```